# Dash graph selected legend items as input to callback

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash, legend-properties, plotly-python

I have a Dash app with a `dcc.Graph` object and a legend for multiple deselectable traces. How can I pass the list of traces selected in the legend as an input to a callback?

Answer (score 0):

Use restyleData input in the callback: `Input("graph-id", "restyleData")`